# Gridview How to Programmatic ally select the very last record and put it in Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I have a Gridview - ObjectDataSource - SQL 2008. 
When the web page is first displayed, I want the very last record to be put in Edit Mode.
Also I want the data from the selected record to be displayed in Textboxes that are used for inserting the record.
Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Protected Sub grdTable_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdTable.DataBound
        grdTable.SetEditRow(grdTable.Rows.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

As long as the text boxes are bound using the Bind() function, the data will appear in the text boxes.